# .git folder dosent show up with the command git init

Tags: git, init

git folder in a folder. So i type `git init` in my command line and it print:
`Reinitialized existing Git repository in C:/Demoo site/My site/SiteWeb/.git/`.  But the folder dosent show up in my folder. What im suppose to do can someone help me please

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable "show hidden folders" in windoes explorer